# DNnClassifier - what class_weight to use for predict method

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create a DNNClassifier for data with 2 classes, but with unbalanced data. I am using class_weight to scale up loss for the low frequency class during training.

```
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
  feature_columns=feature_columns,                                              
  hidden_units=[220, 100, 10],
  n_classes=2,
  dropout=0.5,
  weight_column_name="class_weight",
  model_dir="./tf_model"
)
classifier.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs, steps=500)
```

However, the DNNClassifier also needs class_weight to be set for predict method. What class_weight can I provide for fresh data that I passing through the model for classification?

Thanks,
-Prasad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the answer that either you or I would hope for, but the requirement that the `tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier` `weight_column_name` column be a Feature of the model effectively renders the param entirely useless.

While trying to get to the point where it became evident that this param was a complete waste of time, I commented upon this [Tensor Flow Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8043).

The upshot is that:

- In order for the `DNNClassifier` to use `weight_column_name`, it must be one of the model Features.
- If it is a Feature defined on the model when the model trains, it must be a Feature defined on the model when the model is tested, and it also must be a Feature defined on the model when the model is used for predictions.

First, I tried my test set with the column present, and of course got 99.96% accuracy because training had learned to correlate the weight column value with the label. (I was elated for about 30s ... and thereafter spent several minutes sheepishly moping.)

Then, I tried building a test model without either the weights column or the `weight_column_name` param defined that restored a model trained using the weights column as a feature and the `weight_column_name` param, but got this error:

```
Object was never used (type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>):
<tf.Tensor 'report_uninitialized_variables_1/boolean_mask/Gather:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>
If you want to mark it as used call its "mark_used()" method.
```

I was intrigued by the `mark_used()` bit, so I tried to do this:

`tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("outcome_class_weight").mark_used()`

... but, apparently, that wasn't the Tensor to which the error referred, since I then got the error that `AttributeError: '_RealValuedColumn' object has no attribute 'mark_used'`

Sensing that this param is a bottomless rabbit-hole, it seems that the only ways to address class imbalance are:

1. For every row in the test set, and for predictions, use a value for the `weight_column_name` column that is halfway between the value used by each of the 2 classes. Or, a value that is the mean of all the values for all the classes. I'm going to try this first, but I doubt I'll stick with it long-term unless it results in improved recall: it feels like a gross kludge.
2. Drop down to the low-level API and engineer the loss function manually.  This sounds quite painful to me as a TensorFlow newbie, and will be the option of last resort.  Then again, once I become more facile with TensorFlow, I may wonder why I'm still messing around with the high-level API.
3. Based upon that Tensor Flow Issue's comments, figure out how to incorporate the class weighing into the InputFn only, and not into the model itself in any way.  I'm not convinced I'm actually understanding those comments correctly though, so after some thought and googling, I suspect I'll end up having to abandon this approach empty-handed.
4. Over-sample the inadequately-represented class (my preference) or under-sample the abundantly-represented class. I strongly suspect I'll take this tack long term simply because I already know how to do it reasonably well.  (I'm still bummed about it though, since class weighing seems less potentially error-prone than either under-sampling or over-sampling.)

===Update===

- I tried option 1.  It sunk all metrics.  Moral of the story: you can't use a linear solution for a non-linear model.
- Option 3 was my misunderstanding.  If you define a placeholder feature on a model, the input function must provide data for that feature, period.

So, for now I'm going to oversample my poorly-represented class.

Later, when I'm feeling more confident with TensorFlow, I'll use the low-level API to construct a model that accepts a weights vector that is not a model feature.

Also, this weekend I'll draft up a code for additional comments on the github thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question but the answer is:

> it depends.

You have to decide on that.

One simple approach could be to set the class weight inversely proportional to the number of samples labeled with that class in your dataset.

Comment: I understand that, and that's what I would do for training. However, DNNClassifier needs class_weight even for predict method where you are calling it against unseen data. What class_weight would you set when you call the predict method?

Comment: Thanks Onur, But you wouldn't know which class unseen data belongs to, so you can't apply the same class weights.

Comment: Might it work if you construct a 2nd, new `DNNClassifier` with all the params of the first - especially the `model_dir`, of course - but without the `weight_column_name` param?  (I'll be at this point myself in a week or so with my model, and will post back if it does work.)